# JScrollPane usage

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, paint

I have a JScrollPane and JPanel inside it(I want to draw on JPanel). Also I have a method that draws lines with parametre of length of the line. I want my JScrollPane to scroll if the length of the line is more then the size(height or width) of my JPanel that is on JScrollPane.
How can I do this?

P.S. I've tried jScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible but it doesn't work

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work".  Please explain what is happening and what the desired result is.

Comment: it draws the line to the very end of JPanel(even if the line is longer than the panel's size) and that's all. I want my JScrollPane to scroll(the scrollbars must appear that I can see the full length of the line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example implementing what you want

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class DrawLine {

    JFrame j;
    JPanel p;
    JScrollPane sp;

    public DrawLine() {
        j = new JFrame();
        p = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawLine(20, 20, 250, 250);
            }
        };
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        sp = new JScrollPane(p);
        j.getContentPane().add(sp);
        j.setSize(300, 300);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new DrawLine();
        }
}
```

---

Note the line `p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));` which sets the preferred size of the panel.

Comment: The example may not repaint the component properly and only demonstrates the use of `JScrollPane`, but as you said _"Also I have a method that draws lines with parameter of length of the line."_  it wont be a problem.

Comment: actually I want scrolling when I push the button. I paste this peace p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(weidth, height)) of code into my draw function, but it is simply ignore this line, so line is drawn the same as I mentioned in my first post

Comment: @maks can you post your draw function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the following method in the `LinePanel` class:

```
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(myLine.getWidth(), myLine.getHeight());
  }
```

Make sure that `myLine` object is available to the above method. And, you will get the scrollbars as needed.

*P.S.: I assume `LinePanel` extends `JPanel` and is the panel on which the line is drawn.*

Comment: +1 overriding the getPreferredSize() method to return a dynamical value for the preferred size is the preferred approach over using the setPreferredSize() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the JScrollPanel with the JPanel that it is scrolling.  That is, you need

```
JScrollPane lineScrollPane = new JScrollPane(linePanel);
```

This will create a JScrollPane that automatically sizes itself to scroll over whatever linePanel's size is.

It's important to make sure then, that the panel containing your line actually IS big enough to fit entire line.  That is, you might have something like

```
linePanel.setSize(myLine.getWidth(), myLine.getHeight());
```

or whatever your associated line size is.  Note that something like

```
lineScrollPanel.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
```

will resize the scroll panel but not the thing inside--that is, it will be a 600x400 scroll pane but the inside panel may be bigger smaller, and it will be scrolled.

Comment: actually in Netbeans when I add a JPanel to JScrollPane it automatically associate the JScrollPane with the JPanel. The problem occurs when I do  linePanel.setSize(myLine.getWidth(), myLine.getHeight()); in my code: it clears all lines that are on the panel and scrollbars don't appear

Comment: it's rather hard to have any idea what you are doing wrong without some code in the question.